# Exposing static properties in your Flex class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an actionscript class in my flex app that looks like this:

```
package Assets
{    
    public class AppIcons {

        public function AppIcons() {

        }

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/ico_16.png")]
        public static var Icon_16:Class;

        [Bindable]
        [Embed(source="assets/ico_32.png")]
        public static var Icon_32:Class;    

    }

}
```

I want to know if I can extend this class and create another class that lets me access the properties as instances of that new class. Since these are static, I cannot access these as instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an instance to call static variables. You can access them through the class.

Pattern for static method/variable: `ClassName.StaticVariableName`

So just call:

```
var icon:Class = AppIcons.Icon_16
```

Comment: I know that. But I want to access it from another custom class.

Comment: Lets assume you have instance, not class itself: var appIcons = new AppIcons(); then you can call appIcons.constructor.Icon_16. So use constructor method to call static properties.